# Undefined Variable in Node.js local function

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js

I just want to ask, why my function variable gives an undefined value but I assign a value to it properly. Here's my code.

server.js code

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, listen);

function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
}

function asd(width, height){
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection',

  function (socket) {
  
    console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);

    socket.on('display',
      function(data){
        asd(data.width, data.height);
        console.log(asd.width);
      }

      );
    
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log("Client has disconnected");
    });
  }
);
```

sketch.js code

```js
var circle;
var circles = [];
var zoom = 1;
var newZoom;
var socket;

function setup() {
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  createCanvas(1366, 666);
  circle = new Circle(0, 0, 64);

  var data = {
    width: 1366,
    height: 666
  };

  socket.emit('display', data);

}

function draw() {
  background(60);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  newZoom = (64 / circle.radius*1.5);
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newZoom, 0.1);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-circle.position.x, -circle.position.y);

  for (var x = circles.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (circle.eat(circles[x])) {
      circles.splice(x, 1);
    }
  }

  circle.show();
  circle.update();
  circle.constrain();


  for (var x = 0; x < circles.length; x++) {
    circles[x].show();
  }
}
```

I tried to directly output the data.width in console log and there's a data in there. Please help.

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: @heidarMostafa the asd.width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling new on asd to create an object. Instead you are using it as a basic function.

Try this instead;

```
socket.on('display',
      function(data){
        var myObject = new asd(data.width, data.height);
        console.log(myObject.width);
      }
);
```